# Grep from the end of a file to the beginning

Tags: text-processing, files, grep, tail

I have a file with about 30.000.000 lines (Radius Accounting) and I need to find  the last match of a given pattern.

The command:

```
tac accounting.log | grep $pattern
```

gives what I need, but it's too slow because the OS has to first read the whole file and then send to the pipe.

So, I need something fast that can read the file from the last line to the first.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`tac` only helps if you also use `grep -m 1` (assuming GNU `grep`) to have `grep` stop after the first match:

```
tac accounting.log | grep -m 1 foo
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -m NUM, --max-count=NUM
          Stop reading a file after NUM matching lines.
```

In the example in your question, both `tac` and `grep` need to process the entire file so using `tac` is kind of pointless.

So, unless you use `grep -m`, don't use `tac` at all, just parse the output of `grep` to get the last match:

```
grep foo accounting.log | tail -n 1
```

---

Another approach would be to use Perl or any other scripting language. For example (where `$pattern=foo`):

```
perl -ne '$l=$_ if /foo/; END{print $l}' file
```

or

```
awk '/foo/{k=$0}END{print k}' file
```

Comment: I'm using tac because I need to find the last match of a given pattern.
Using your suggestion "grep -m1" the execution time goes from 0m0.597s to 0m0.007s \o/.
Thanks everybody!

Comment: @HábnerCosta you're very welcome. I understand why you're using `tac`, my point was that it doesn't help unless you also use `-m` since the file still needs to be read in full by two programs. Otherwise, you could just search for all occurences and keep only the last one as I do with `tail -n 1`.

Comment: Why do you say "tac [...] needs to process the entire file"? The first thing tac does is seek to the end of the file and read a block from the end. You can verify this yourself with strace(1). When combined with `grep -m`, it should be quite efficient.

Comment: @camh when combined with `grep -m` it is. The OP was not using `-m` so both grep and tac were processing the whole thing.

Comment: Could you please expand on the meaning of the `awk` line?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez that will just save the current line (`$0`) as the variable `k` if the current line matches the string `foo` (`/foo/{ something }` is like `if(/foo/){ something }`). Then, at the end of the file (`END{}`) it will print the current value of `k`, so the last line that matched the string `foo`. I hope that's clear. Feel free to ping me in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) if you want mor details.

Comment: OK, Terdon, thanks you. So I understand the full file must/will be read (browsed/processed) with your `awk` method, even when we are only searching for the last appearance.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez yes. If you want to to avoid that, use the first approach, with `tac`.

Comment: +1 million for the perl -ne example because it uses NO PIPES. That's hugely important if you're running the command via Ansible (as pipes will contaminate $? exit status).

Answer (score 15):

The reason why

```
tac file | grep foo | head -n 1
```

doesn't stop at the first match is because of buffering.

Normally, `head -n 1` exits after reading a line. So `grep` should get a SIGPIPE and exit as well as soon as it writes its second line.

But what happens is that because its output is not going to a terminal, `grep` buffers it. That is, it's not writing it until it has accumulated enough (4096 bytes in my test with GNU grep).

What that means is that `grep` will not exit before it has written 8192 bytes of data, so probably quite a few lines.

With GNU `grep`, you can make it exit sooner by using `--line-buffered` which tells it to write lines as soon as they are found regardless of whether goes to a terminal or not. So `grep` would then exit upon the second line it finds.

But with GNU `grep` anyway, you can use `-m 1` instead as @terdon has shown, which is better as it exits at the first match.

If your `grep` is not the GNU `grep`, then you can use `sed` or `awk` instead. But `tac`  being a GNU command, I doubt you'll find a system with `tac` where `grep` is not GNU `grep`.

```
tac file | sed "/$pattern/!d;q"                             # BRE
tac file | P=$pattern awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["P"] {print; exit}' # ERE
```

Some systems have `tail -r` to do the same thing as GNU `tac` does.

Note that, for regular (seekable) files, `tac` and `tail -r` are efficient because they do read the files backward, they're not just reading the file fully in memory before printing it backward (as [@slm's sed approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112175/22565) or `tac` on non-regular files would).

On systems where neither `tac` nor `tail -r` are available, the only options are to implement the backward-reading by hand with programming languages like `perl` or use:

```
grep -e "$pattern" file | tail -n1
```

Or:

```
sed "/$pattern/h;$!d;g" file
```

But those mean finding all the matches and only print the last one.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution that will find the location of first occurrence of pattern from last:

```
tac -s "$pattern" -r accounting.log | head -n 1
```

This makes use of the `-s` and `-r` switches of `tac` which are as follows:

```
-s, --separator=STRING
use STRING as the separator instead of newline

-r, --regex
interpret the separator as a regular expression
```

Comment: Except you will lose everything that is between the start of the line and the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using sed

Showing some alternative methods to [@Terdon's fine answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112173/7453) using `sed`:

```
$ sed '1!G;h;$!d' file | grep -m 1 $pattern
$ sed -n '1!G;h;$p' file | grep -m 1 $pattern
```

#### Examples

```
$ seq 10 > file

$ sed '1!G;h;$!d' file | grep -m 1 5
5

$ sed -n '1!G;h;$p' file | grep -m 1 5
5
```

#### Using Perl

As a bonus here's a little easier notation in Perl to remember:

```
$ perl -e 'print reverse <>' file | grep -m 1 $pattern
```

#### Example

```
$ perl -e 'print reverse <>' file | grep -m 1 5
5
```

Comment: That's (especially the `sed` one) likely to be several orders of magnitude slower than `grep 5 | tail -n1` or `sed '/5/h;$!d;g'`. It will also potentially use a lot of memory. It's not a lot more portable as you're still using GNU's `grep -m`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to search for all the log files.

This command shows the file name.

```
tac *.log | grep -m 4 "In controller create" *.log
```

this command will us the last occurrence of string match.

```
tac *.log | grep -m 4 "In controller create"
```

Comment: Giving `grep` files to read will make it ignore its standard input stream. In your first example command, the input from `tac` would be ignored.  The user in the question only has a single log file, and their issue is the speed of reading it with `tac` to find the last match of their pattern. You do not seem to address this.